Ring activating substiuents
Why is phenylamine more electron rich compared to phenol? How does the $\mathrm{NH}_2$ group increase the electron density of the benzene ring more than the OH?
Additionally, why does a negative charge increase the substituent ring activating ability? E.g., phenoxide is more electron rich compared to phenol .

Review the guide How to ask and Asking FAQs to prevent clarification requests, objections,  downvoting or closure.

Two effects are in balance here: the negative inductive effect and the donation of lone pairs into the system. While it is true that the donation of lone pairs from the heteroatom are delocalized into the ring system in both molecules (from oxygen in phenol, nitrogen in aniline/phenylamine), consider the electronegativities of both nitrogen and oxygen: oxygen is far more electronegative, so while the lone pair donation does occur, the electron density within the whole ring system is just a little closer to oxygen. Nitrogen, with its lower electronegativity, activates the ring system even more, as the lone pair is more available to delocalize all across the ring system. As Clayden's Organic Chemistry puts it:

Because nitrogen is less electronegative than oxygen, the lone pair is higher in energy and so even more available to interact with the π system than is the lone pair on oxygen.

As for why the negative charge increases substituent ring activating activity: the lone pair that oxygen now gains can be delocalized into the system more effectively. Why? Consider the resonant structures for phenol and phenoxide. In phenol, the pi-donation results in a positive formal charge on oxygen, which is to say the electron density around oxygen is relatively high, with a double bond, one lone pair, and one bonded pair (to hydrogen). In phenoxide, where the oxygen has 3 lone pairs, the electron density around oxygen is actually lower than in phenol, as the oxygen has a double bond and two lone pairs -- this indicates that the lone pair donated in phenoxide is delocalized more evenly across the entire ring, making the entire system even more reactive. In fact, phenol is weakly acidic because phenoxide is more stable than phenol. The same effect on an even stronger scale is true for a negative charge on aniline's heteroatom, for reasons outlined above.

Thanks for the respond! When there is a positive formal charge on oxygen, did you mean that the electron density around O is lower? Because doesn't a positive formal charge means the O atom is more electron deficient?

It is actually the opposite. Remember that formal charge is not the electrostatic charge, and assumes all the electrons in bonds are shared evenly between atoms, regardless of electronegativity. It doesn't take into account the fact that these electrons are shared unevenly within the covalent bond when one atom is more electronegative. A higher number of covalent bonds to the more electronegative atom (as seen in positive FC) means that it will have increased electron density around it, and not that the "positively charged" atom actually has an empty orbital in which it can accept electrons.

Oh okay thank you. Sorry my concepts regarding this is shaky as resonance structure or formal charge is not in my school curriculum. I am just asking these questions so I don't have to blindly memorise the explanations in my notes.
